# I need the first field of each row from a mysql query to be a property name and the second field to be the value

Tags: node.js, multilingual, mysql2

I'm setting up a site using node.js. I want users to be able to select between English and Japanese (and possibly more languages in the future). I've got a table called 'language' that looks something like this.

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
|  variable  |      en     |     jp      |
+============+=============+=============+
| 'username' | 'User Name' | 'ユーザ名'   |
+------------+-------------+-------------|
| 'password' | 'Password'  | 'パスワード' |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I can query the database just fine using the mysql2/promise module...

```
const lang = 'jp';    
const [rows, schema] = await db.query("SELECT variable, ?? FROM language", [lang]);
console.log(rows);
```

but this format isn't really useful to me...

```
[
  TextRow { variable: 'username', jp: 'ユーザ名' },
  TextRow { variable: 'password', jp: 'パスワード' }
]
```

I'd like a user selected object with the 'variable' fields as property names and the fields of the selected language as the values. That way I can easily pass it to the view engine. Something like...

```
const language = {'username' : 'ユーザ名',
                  'password' : 'パスワード'
                  }

res.render("mypage", { 'language': language });
```

...but something I can maintain in the database.

Also, if there is a more efficient or 'common practice' way to maintain a multi-language site, I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it would be better if you use JSON data type for multi-language for the same value.

```
+------------+-------------+
|  variable  |      value      |
+============+=============+
| 'username' | {jp:'ユーザ名', 
              en: 'username' } |
+------------+-------------+
```

See MySql reference for JSON data format: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I need to query for each string I use on the page from an object that contains any number of languages the user doesn't need? It seems like I should be able to make one query to load the whole dictionary for the user-selected language only.